# Symfony cannot autowire service no such service exists

Tags: php, symfony, autowired

**UPDATE**

I moved a Command from CoreBundle to AssetBundle and forgot to change the namespace path. Simply renamed /CoreBundle/Command to /AssetBundle/Command and everything worked again.

I am getting an Symfony 4.4 autowire issue that i can not resolve.

This error is about a service being injected in a helper. The helper is for the the Exporter service. The exporter service is being build by dependency injection file and there is where the helpers are getting added.

This is the defaults in my Bundle service file

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true 
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false
```

This is the helper with the tag that i use

```
X\ExportBundle\Service\Exporter\ExportColumn\Helper\AttributeHelper:
    tags:
        - { name: column_helper, alias: attribute_helper }
```

This is the interface for the helper

```
class AttributeHelper implements ExportColumnHelperInterface
```

This is the constructor of the helper

```
/**
 * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
 * @param AssetManager $assetManager
 */
public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, AssetManager $assetManager) 
{
    $this->assetManager = $assetManager;
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}
```

This is the error i get

```
Cannot autowire service "X\ExportBundle\Service\Exporter\ExportColumn\Helper\AttributeHelper": argument "$assetManager" of method "__construct()" references class "X\AssetBundle\Service\Asset\AssetManager" but no such service exists.
```

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Is there `App\:   resource: '../src/*'   exclude: '../src/{Helper,Entity,Migrations,Kernel.php}'` in service.yml ?

Comment: Please share more details - where did you configure the autowiring, and how?

Comment: @SinisterGlitch If you've a solution you need to add it in the answer section and not inside the question.

Answer (score 0):

Add `autowire: true` to the service config in yaml

Comment: I updated my question and added service file headers, i had everything autowired and it worked before. It suddenly does not work anymore.

Comment: Is `AssetManager` implementing an intefrace by any chance? If so, you might want to add an alias in the services config as described in the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/service_container/autowiring.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to manually register the class in `services.yml`.

```
GlobalServicesBundle\Services\AwsCloudStorageService: ~
```